# Using VPython how to call Class sphere positions?

Tags: python, vpython

Through using VPython, I am able to get the program I am working on to generate multiple balls by calling the same class. I am also able to have the balls appear within a selected random range when they are generated (across x, y and z).

However, I am currently stumped on how I get to call the pos / position function from within my loop - as I would like to have the balls move.

Please see my code so far below.

If I call Ball.pos it states as undefined, but if I place my positioning via self.position, only one ball is generated, as they are not being referred to from under the sphere details?

```
from visual import *
from random import *
scene.title = "Multi Balls"

wallBm = box(pos=(0,-6,0), size=(12.2,0.1,12.1), color=color.blue, opacity=0.4)

vscale = 0.1
deltat = 0.005
t = 0
scene.autoscale = False
i = 0

totalBalls = 10

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.velocity = vector(0,5,0)
        #vel sample ([5,10,15,20,25],3)
        sphere (pos=(randrange (-6,6),randrange (-6,6),randrange (-6,6)), radius=0.5, color=color.cyan)

while True:
    rate(100)
    if i < totalBalls:
        Ball()
        i = i + 1

    t = 5 + deltat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Inheritance from frame:

```
class Ball(frame):
    def __init__(self, pos=(randrange (-6,6),randrange (-6,6),randrange (-6,6))):
        frame.__init__(self,pos=pos)
        self.velocity = vector(0,5,0)
        sphere(frame=self,pos=pos,radius=0.5, color=color.cyan)
listOfBalls=[]
while True:
    rate(100)
    for i in range(totalBalls):
        listOfBalls.append(Ball())
```

now try again!
You can call each Ball's position by calling `listOfBalls[3].pos`. I hope this helps!